Deriving equation for a Dynamic programming Puzzle
I solved the following puzzle https://leetcode.com/problems/unique-paths/description/ here at leetcode using programming. It is not very difficult to reason about how to computationally get the answer. But I have no intuition on how to derive a mathematical formula to calculate the answer given values n and m. I will copy the puzzle here for easier access:

There is a robot on an $m\times n$ grid. The robot is initially located at the top-left corner (i.e., grid[$0$][$0$]). The robot tries to move to the bottom-right corner (i.e., grid[$m - 1$][$n - 1$]). The robot can only move either down or right at any point in time.
Given the two integers $m$ and $n$, return the number of possible unique paths that the robot can take to reach the bottom-right corner.

Is there a recurrence relation that we can use to derive a function that gives us the answer?

Not a recurrence relation but a direct reasoning: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1714514/a-problem-in-combinatorics-counting-number-of-different-paths-on-a-grid-of-poin

(total number of ways) = (number of ways whose first step is right) + (number of ways whose first step is down), so $f(m,n)=f(m-1,n)+f(m,n-1)$ (in non-base cases).

Yes, I used that for computing the answer https://gist.github.com/YohannesKifle/14ee7ba083cb16d5bb45cd0f2824bdf0 . But I could not find closed form solution or maybe there might not be one

Thanks for the link Anne and thanks Karl for the answer. I think this question is a duplicate. I will make it answered for now as I have found my answer

Look at it this way: on an $m \times n$ grid, the robot has to take $m + n - 2$ steps in total. Of those $m + n - 2$ steps, exactly $m - 1$ are downward and $n - 1$ are to the right.
It thus comes down to choosing the $m - 1$ steps where the robot goes down, out of the total $m + n - 2$ steps that have to be taken. Then, the remaining $n - 1$ steps are used to go right.
Using this reasoning, the total number of valid paths equals:
$${m + n - 2 \choose m - 1}$$
In the first example you referred to, you thus find:
$${3 + 7 - 2 \choose 3 - 1} = {8 \choose 2} = 28$$
